# ftp_site() doesn't want to change CHMOD on the folders

Tags: php, joomla, chmod

I have a joomla page on which I want to install a few extensions. However due to the chmod permissions I am unable to upload and install the packages. Following the guide [here](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_solve_Installation_errors_Extension_Manager) I can see that in order for the plugins to be installed **there are too many folders which permissions have to be changed**.

For that I am creating a script which will iterate through each of the required folders and will change the permissions from 0775 to 0777.

```
<?php
// SET THE DESIRED CHMOD VALUE
if ($_GET['chmod']) { 
        $ftp_chmod = $_GET['chmod']; 
    } 
    else { 
        $ftp_chmod = "0755"; 
    }
echo "chmod=" . $ftp_chmod . '<br />';
echo getcwd() . '<br />';
$currdir = getcwd(); // get current directory

// ESTABLISH AN FTP LOGIN SESSION
$ftp_server='example.com';
$ftp_user='username';
$ftp_pass='*****';
$conn_id = ftp_connect("$ftp_server");

if ( ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass) ) {
    echo 'FTP CONNECTION IS SUCCESSFULL <br />';
}
else {
    echo 'BAD CREDENTIALS';
    exit();
}

// Define the folders for which the CHMODE will change the values
// There must be a leading space in front of the path in order for CHMOD to work
$folder_path = array(
    ' ' . $currdir . '/modules/',
    ' ' . $currdir . '/plugins/'
    ' ' . $currdir . '/tmp/',
    ' ' . $currdir . '/cache/'
);

echo '<br />';
foreach ( $folder_path as $key => $value )
{
    $path = trim($value); // The leading space must be trimed fo is_dir() function to work

    if ( is_dir($path) == true ) {

        echo $path . ' -- ' . '<span style="color: #00B200">OK</span><br />';
        echo 'CHMOD ' . $ftp_chmod . '  ' . $value . '<br />';

        if (ftp_site($conn_id, 'CHMOD ' . $ftp_chmod . $value)) {
            echo 'CHMOD ' . $ftp_chmod . ' IS <span style="color: #00B200">SUCCESSFULL</span><br /><br />';
        }
        else {
            echo '<span style="color: crimson">CHMOD FAILED!</span><br /><br />';
        }
    }
    else {
        echo $path . ' -- ' . '<span style="color: crimson"><b>NOT EXIST</b></span><br />';
    } // end if ( is_dir($path) == true ) else

} // end foreach ( $folder_path as $key => $value )

ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

*Please note that the actual script is much larger due to the many folders that need to be changed. The folders shown in* **$folder_path = array()** *are just an example*

When I execute the script on my server i get the folowind output:

```
chmod=0777
/var/www/example/data/www/example.com
FTP CONNECTION IS SUCCESSFULL 

/var/www/example/data/www/example.com/modules/ -- OK
CHMOD 0777 /var/www/example/data/www/example.com/modules/
CHMOD FAILED!

/var/www/example/data/www/example.com/plugins/ -- OK
CHMOD 0777 /var/www/example/data/www/example.com/plugins/
CHMOD FAILED!

/var/www/example/data/www/example.com/tmp/ -- OK
CHMOD 0777 /var/www/example/data/www/example.com/tmp/
CHMOD FAILED!

/var/www/example/data/www/example.com/cache/ -- OK
CHMOD 0777 /var/www/example/data/www/example.com/cache/
CHMOD FAILED!
```

**DOES ANYONE HAVE ANY IDEA ON HOW TO CHANGE THE CHMOD VALUE ON SO MANY FOLDERS?**

---

UPDATE:
I also have to mention that I have tried to change the CHMOD value on each folder individually via FTP client and it is successfull. The problem comes when i have to change them through the script. **The same acc with root privilege access** is used from the FTP client and the script to change the files!

Comment: Rather than trying to do the chmod via FTP, could you write a PHP script to do it, upload it and execute it on the server? You could `exec('sudo chmod 777 dir')` if your web server user doesn't have permissions to do it maybe?

Comment: How would the sudo query the needed password when it's executed via php? OP also mentions that chmod via FTP client actually works, so doing it as webuser likely *won't* work

Comment: @nyarlathotep `proc_open()` it then? This would only be any issue if the Apache (or whatever) user does not own the directories, which there is a good chance it does.

Comment: I am now begging to thing that the path that is returned from `echo getcwd()` can not be used by ftp_site() function. That is this line here: `if (ftp_site($conn_id, 'CHMOD ' . $ftp_chmod . $value))` so I may need to use only a relative path like `/www/example.com/modules/`

Comment: This is the output when I change the CHMOD value from the filezilla client" 
`Status: Set permissions of '/www/example/modules' to '777'`
`Command: SITE CHMOD 777 modules`

Comment: @Spirit `getcwd()` returns the full path, relative to the root of the local file system. Chances are the root of the FTP server is not the root of the file system, so `getcwd()` will not really help you, at least not without modifying the value it returns to strip the beginning of the string.

Comment: Yup... I realized that and I did a small modification to the script which made it work. What i did was just subtracted the required number of characters from the path returned from the getcwd() and that solved my problem.

Comment: Thank you guys from the help I will post the answer in a 24h or so.. since I a newbie on this forum I don't have the privilege to post answers to my own questions for 24 hours or so :)

Comment: @DaveRandom Can you post your last comment as an answer to this question I will gladly accept it :)

Comment: @Spirit I can, but it will help you get more rep if I don't, and you just wait for the 24 hours so you can answer it yourself and accept your own answer - I don't need the rep as much as you ;-)

Comment: Well thanks a lot Dave I temporary posted my solution as an update of the question :)

Comment: @Spirit: Don't write solutions in questions, please. Write an answer.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal | Thats THE problem :) I am a newbie and I will be able to post an answer and accept it in a 25h or so...

Comment: @Spirit: Then you wait 25 hours. There is a reason for that limitation to exist, and it's not to encourage you to put answers in inappropriate places instead.

Comment: Chill out buddy. I will remove the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to the problem. What I did was a small modification to the foreach part of the script which made it work. Basically I just subtracted the required number of characters from the path returned from the getcwd() and that solved my problem.

Here is the change that i did:

```
---- REST OF THE SCRIPT OMITED -----

foreach ( $folder_path as $key => $value )
{
    $path = trim($value); // The leading space must be trimed fo is_dis() function to work

    if ( is_dir($path) == true ) {

        $value_short = substr($value, 19); // <------------- Subtruct the required number od chars in order to create a relative path

        echo $path . ' -- ' . '<span style="color: #00B200">OK</span><br />';
        echo 'CHMOD ' . $ftp_chmod . '  ' . $value_short . '<br />';


        if (ftp_site($conn_id, "CHMOD $ftp_chmod $value_short")) { // <-------------- Use the relative path in the function
            echo 'CHMOD ' . $ftp_chmod . ' IS <span style="color: #00B200">SUCCESSFULL</span><br /><br />';
        }
        else {
            echo '<span style="color: crimson">CHMOD FAILED!</span><br /><br />';
        }
    }
    else {
        echo $path . ' -- ' . '<span style="color: crimson"><b>NOT EXIST</b></span><br />';
    } // end if ( is_dir($path) == true ) else

} // end foreach ( $folder_path as $key => $value )

---- REST OF THE SCRIPT OMITED -----
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try just enabling [Joomla's FTP layer](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=1278556) before installing components/plugins etc?